# how to upgrade a dropdown code in angular-bootstrap from 0.11.2 to 0.13.0?

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

got a drop down code in angular-bootstrap 0.11.2, now when upgrading to 0.13.0, it can not drop down any more:

1) 0.11.2 sample, it's working:

http://jsfiddle.net/f1etvcnb/2/

```
<a href="*" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About <bclass="caret"></b></a>
```

2) 0.13.0 sample, it's not dropping down:

http://jsfiddle.net/f1etvcnb/3/

```
<a href="*" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About <b class="caret"></b></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the old docs, you need to include the `dropdown` attribute in the enclosing `li` element and the `dropdown-toggle` attribute on the element thats toggling (`a` in your case). I've updated your jsFiddle to include these changes. On a side note, I would strongly recommend you use one of the newer version of angular bootstrap ui. The `0.13` and `0.11` versions are very old. You get more features and configuration options with the new ones, not to mention the benefits of bug fixes and performance over time.

**[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f1etvcnb/4/)**

Comment: Thanks, it works. for upgrading beyond 0.13, my angular is still in 1.3.20, so upgrading for now is not yet an option.